# integrate series in y-axis in highchart-chart polymer wrapper

Tags: spring, highcharts, polymer

I've been trying highcharts-chart component for polymer but I can't seem to get the syntax right, I want a chart just like the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2kuc.png) and here's what I tried:

```
  <highcharts-chart id="Chart" x-Axis='["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]' type="spline"title="Monthly Average Temperature" subtitle="Source: WorldClimate.com" x-label="Months"  y-label="Average"
    y-Axis='{name= "Tokyo", series= [7.0, 6.9, 9.5]},
    {name= "New York", series= [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7},
    {name= "Berlin", series= [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5]},
    {name= "London", series= [3.9, 4.2, 5.7}'></highcharts-chart>
```

Comment: So you are using this wrapper? https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart Did you read all information about installation of this wrapper? I think that in case of using specific wrappers you may contact directly the creator of this wrapper on github.